# File iteration, checking line existence

Tags: python, file, iteration

I am reading through a file using a for loop like this...

```
f = open("somefile.txt")

for line in f:
    do stuff
```

except for each line I read i need to take an item from the line ahead of it and put it in the current line. What is the best way to do this? Is there a way to read the next line or get some item from it without reading it?

Comment: Or can I somehow check if the next line exists before trying to read it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'put it in the current line' ??? You want to modify a recorded line on the hard drive  with data present in the line ahead ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, and you want to work on each line in turn, using some value from the next line, my suggestion would be simply to store the value you are currently reading, and work on the last value. Work in reverse - the `last_line` is your current line and line is the next one.

```
last_line = None

with open("somefile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if not last_line == None:
            do_stuff(last_line, extract_needed_part(line))
        last_line = line
do_stuff(last_line) #The final line without anything following it.
```

In mathematical terms, instead of line n and line n+1, do line n-1 and line n. Same effect.

The upside to this method is it doesn't mean loading the entire file at the beginning.

Comment: I wish I could vote up your answer but unfortunately I don't have 15 reputation yet hah. Thank you though, I found this helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If your file is not huge, you can read it into memory and use it there:

```
f = open("somefile.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

for index, value in enumerate(lines):
    # Check if next line exists
    if index + 1 > len(lines):
        next_line = lines(index + 1)
        # do something with line and next_line
```

**Edit:**

For large files, it would be easiest to just remember your previous line:

```
f = open("somefile.txt")
previous_line = f.readline()
for line in f:
    # Do something with line and previous_line
    print(line, previous_line)
    # Save this line for the next iteration
    previous_line = line
```

There might be edge cases depending on what your data looks like. Do your lines always come in pairs or do you just need a bit of info from the next line in certain circumstances.

For instance this code won't do anything if your file only has one line.

Comment: The problem is that the files are quite large, I want to do the processing without having to store every line in memory initially. I was hoping there would be some method I do not know about. This is a good backup option if all else fails though. Thanks for replying.

Comment: In your example for your edit, which is pretty much a repeat of my answer, except you are not using with (which you should) and for the first execution, previous_line and line will be the same.

Comment: I do have a try, IOException clause in my actual code instead of a with (for compatability). This is more of a generalization, where we can assume the file exists and will return no error. Nonetheless the consensus seems to be to simply hang on to the previous line. If its the best way, I will use that.

Comment: Hi Lattyware, The "for line in f" construct does NOT reset the file pointer of f, therefore the first value "line" is assigned is the SECOND line of the file. Give it a try.

Comment: @secretmike My mistake. It's still good practice to use ``with``, however.

Answer (score 0):

If your file fits in memory, you can try something like this:

```
f = open('somefile.txt')
lines = f.read().splitlines()

for current_line, next_line in zip(lines, lines[1:]):
    print current_line
    print next_line
    print '-------'
```

The code above basically reads all the lines and uses `zip` to create a list of tuples that contains the current line and the next one.

Edit: Alternatively, for long files, you can use [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) library as follows:

```
import itertools
f = open('somefile.txt')
i1, i2 = itertools.tee(f)
lines = itertools.izip(i1, itertools.islice(i2, 1, None))
for current_line, next_line in lines:
    print current_line
    print next_line
    print '-------'
```

In this case:

- `itertools.tee` is used to create two indenpendent iterators (one for the current line and one for the next line) that use the original file iterator.
- `itertools.slice` is used to start the next line iterator in the second line.
- `itertools.izip` is used to join the results of both iterators line by line in a tuple.

Edit 2: As suggested by @eyquem, you can also open the file twice:

```
import itertools
f = open('somefile.txt')
g = open('somefile.txt')
lines = itertools.izip(f, itertools.islice(g, 1, None))
for current_line, next_line in lines:
    print current_line
    print next_line
    print '-------'
```

Comment: There's no need to use **tee()**. Just define another file handler: ``g = open('somefile.txt')`` and make it move one line ahead with ``g.readline()`` . Then ``lines = ((f.readline(),line) for line in g)``

Comment: @eyquem Thanks for your comment. I've edited the answer to include your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('somefile.txt') as f, open('somefile.txt') as g:
    g.readline()
    lines = ( (f.readline(),line) for line in g)
        for precline,aheadline in lines:
            # do what you want
```